# How can you create a unique key for two interchangable integers?

Tags: math, hash, greatest-common-divisor

I am trying to write a simple caching mechanism for Euclid's method of finding the GCD of two numbers:

```
gcd(a,0) = a
gcd(a,b) = gcd(b, a % b)
```

Note that `gcd(a,b) == gcd(b,a)`.

For the cache, I need to find a key for a given `(a,b)` or `(b,a)`, with `0 < a < 20` and `0 < b < 20`.

Of course, I could use `key = a*20 + b`, or `key = a + b*20`, but those are asymmetric - the key for `(1,5)` is different than for `(5,1)`.

How could I implement this?

Comment: @Wooble - C++, but it's applicable to any language, really.

Comment: not necessarily; e.g. in Python, `tuple(sorted(a,b))` makes a perfectly good key and doesn't require limiting the input values.

Comment: @Wooble - Very true. I always forget about those nifty little tricks in Python/Ruby/etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, sort the numbers.

```
key = a > b ? b*20 + a : a*20 + b;
```

Answer (score 2):

Let c be min(a,b) and d be max(a,b). Then, your hash function c*20 + d is symmetric with respect to a and b.